# Add span to archive post count

Tags: wordpress, count, widget, archive

In WordPress you can add a span to the `wp_list_categories()` function with something like:

```
function style_the_list_count($links) {
$links = str_replace('</a> (', '</a> <span class="listCount">(', $links);
$links = str_replace(')', ')</span>', $links);
return $links;
}
add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'style_the_list_count');
```

but I want to target the Archive's `Show post counts` but after looking for the function to tie into I've been unable to locate what should be used.  I've tried `wp_get_archives` from my searches but no luck and when I looked under the post [Creating an Archive Index](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index) I didn't see anything mentioned.  Is there a way I can hook into the Archive count or a way I can add a span tag to every instance of a widget's checked `Show post counts` for all of the default widgets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wp_get_archives()` itself doesn't have any useful filters we can hook in to, but `get_archives_link()` (which it calls and passes the post count output to) does.

You can use an almost identical function and hook it to the `get_archives_link` filter:

```
function so_40551791_style_the_archive_count($links) {
    $links = str_replace('</a>&nbsp;(', '</a> <span class="archiveCount">(', $links);
    $links = str_replace(')', ')</span>', $links);
    return $links;
}

add_filter('get_archives_link', 'so_40551791_style_the_archive_count');
```

Note, the `&nbsp;` where there was a space before.